# Custom deserializer for a particular state NGXS Storage Plugin

Tags: angular, ngxs

The storage plugin specify that I can use custom deserializer. The problem is it doesnt provide anything on how to use it. Is the deserializer provided be used on all state classes?

What I need is to have a specific deserializer in each States.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Deserialize* is one of the options of **NgxsStoragePluginModule**:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      deserialize(data) {
        return JSON.parse(data) // by default it returns parsed data
      }    
    })
  ],
})
```

You set one for all. I personally didn't try this. But according to docs, this way we can define options to storage plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I think they need to consider multiple deserializer :) Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to define your exported function first, otherwise it will fail with AOT compile.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      deserialize(data) {
        // Do deserialization
      },
    }),
...
```

This works with/without AOT:

```
export function deserialize(data: any) {
  // Do deserialization
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      deserialize,
    }),
...
```

https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1123#issuecomment-605933173